# Having trouble with a TypeError in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4

Hey all I am new to programming and I need help with a problem. In this problem we are asked to create a super class "Person" and a sub class Instructor and Student

The main problem I am having is that I have a method name that needs to retrive the name of the Person and in the console x.name works but the required x.name() does not and gives me a TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

```
from datetime import date

class Person:

    def __init__(self, name, year):
        self.name = str(name)
        self.year = year
    def age(self):
        return date.today().year- self.year
    def name(self):
        return (self.name)

class Instructor(Person):

    def __init__(self, name, age, degree):
        Person.__init__(self, name, age)
    def degree(self):
        return (self.degree)

class Student(Person):

    def __init__(self, name, age, major = "major"):
        Person.__init__(self, name, age)
    def major(self):
        return (self.major)
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name `name` conflicts. It's used for method and attribute.

Use different names for them.

```
class Person:

    def __init__(self, name, year):
        self.name = str(name)  # <----
        self.year = year

    def age(self):
        return date.today().year- self.year

    def name(self):  # <---- same name is used.
        return (self.name)
```